# How do I tweak "sender" in an event?

Tags: c#, events

I have a code that may use `randomLabel` as a `sender` that fires an event. In this code, I attempt to tweak `sender`'s Font properties but it seems to give a compile error. Is there any way to fix this?

```
    private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        randomLabel.MouseEnter += RandomLabel_MouseEnter;
    }

    private void RandomLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sender.Font = new Font(sender.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
```

Comment: You need to cast `sender` from `object` to `randomLabel` type.

Comment: `sender` is an **`object`** and objects don't have a `Font` property. You would need to cast it as a control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "tweak" the sender, but you have to cast it to the correct type so you can access its properties and methods.

```
private void RandomLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sender2 = sender as Label;
    if (sender2 != null)
        sender2.Font = new Font(sender2.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `sender` to the appropriate control. E.g.

```
private void RandomLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = sender as Control;
    if (sender != null)
    {
        control.Font = new Font(control.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("sender");
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep the things simple. Just cast `sender` to `Control`: `((Control)sender).Font`. By the way, `is` then cast isn't efficient - the right way to go is `as`, then null-checking (see @NightOwl888's answer).

Answer (score 0):

`sender` is of type `object` which does not have a `Font` property. You'd need to cast it to the appropriate type first

Assuming it is a Label..

```
((Label)sender).Font = new Font(((Label)sender).Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

It is likely a good choice to make sure `sender` is actually the type you expect it is using either the `is` or `as` operators before hand though. Just in case